# ¿Cómo hacer una radio FM que se transmite en una pagina web?

Tags: javascript

Necesito que me ayuden sobre este tema, cuando escribo este código sí funciona

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://10.0.2.2:8000/;stream.mp3");
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Pero cuando pongo este link (https://planeta.pe/radioenvivo) no me funciona:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource("http://planeta.pe/radioenvivo"); 
mediaPlayer.prepare();
mediaPlayer.start();
```

Comment: Qué quieres decir con que no funciona? Qué pasa? Qué mensaje de error sale?

Comment: no reproduce el radio

Comment: Algún mensaje en la consola?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden.

Comment: Si no me equivoco a `setDataSource` tienes que pasarle un archivo, cosa que no estás haciendo.